# Controlling visibility of html controls using databinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I'm trying to control whether or not some `<td>` elements are rendered or not using databinding and `runat="server"`:

```
<td runat="server" visible="<%# this.SomeBool %>"><tr>Hello world!</tr></td>
```

The trouble is that the `SomeBool` property just isnt being called.

If I explicitly set visible to false, like this:

```
<td runat="server" visible="False"><tr>Hello world!</tr></td>
```

Then all is well and the element is not rendered.

How do I get this databinding to work?

Comment: How do you know SomeBool isn't being called? Did you check it with a breakpoint in the debugger?  What does the code do?  Does it return a string or a bool?  Which control are you using for the databinding?  Also, minor point, but your td and tr tags are reversed.

Comment: No need to stick [solved] just set your answer as the correct one in a few days

Comment: Meh, just figured that until I'm able to mark my answer as correct I'd put it as solved so people realise... well that its solved.

Comment: Editing the title to remove [solved] is more effective at steering the question than downvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why my method wasnt being called was because the DataBind() method on my page wasn't being invoked - even just putting the following into the page somewhere did nothing:

```
<%# "Hello world" %>
```

I had to add a call to `this.DataBind()` to the top of my page:

```
<%@ Page ... %>
<% this.DataBind(); %>
```

And everyting then worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

`<td <%# this.SomeBool ? "" : "style=\"display:none;\""  %>><tr>Hello world!</tr></td>`

Answer (score 1):

Try single quotes around the <% %> tags:

```
<tr runat="server" visible='<%# this.SomeBool %>'><td>Hello world!</td></tr>
```

Sergio's idea looks neat, too.